# A problems with refreshing DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using a DataGridView with bounded List of objects in my application. So I have:

```
grid.DataSource = Files.Instance.List;
```

in my form load event and than I want to have two buttons - for adding and removing items from the list (so also from the grid), I though it should be as simple as:

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    Files.Instance.List.Add(new DelphiFile { FilePath = openFileDialog.FileName });
    grid.Refresh();
}
```

I'm only setting up the start path here, I wanted the rest parameters to be set by user in the grid view.
The item is added correctly but unfortunatelly it doesnt appear on the list, why?

I also have issues with deleting items:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in grid.SelectedRows)
{
   Files.Instance.List.Remove(row.DataBoundItem as DelphiFile);
}
grid.Refresh();
```

items are deleted correctly but again the grid doesn't seem to refresh and I'm even getting an exception because the last item in the grid doesn't have a value than :O .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `Files.Instance.List`?

Comment: It's a generic list of DelphiFile objects where DelphiFile is my class.

Comment: if so, my guess is right, see my answer for using `BindingList<...>` instead, it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you declared `Files.Instance.List` as of type `List<DelphiFile>`, so when the collection is changed, the `dataGridView` doesn't know about that, use `BindingList<DelphiFile>` instead.

Comment: Wow, it was so easy :O
It works very well, thanks very much for help ! :)